# Unity - Emission Material on Top of UI

Tags: unity, materials, unity-ui

I've already uploaded this question in the Unity forums but only got a response but not an answer or solution. Here's a link to the original post: https://forum.unity.com/threads/emission-material-on-top-of-ui.1032337/?fbclid=IwAR1X3sXn1X8XcEXHXjD3wffiQxuDK6KAjMF57XDv9RUb1FsofklORfDeRm0

In my latest project I tried to do a transition between scenes in the most simple way: Darkening the screen.

The problem is, when the image goes fully opaque (alpha = 1), there are emission materials that are clearly visible "through" the image.

This only happens to the emission type:

I'll leave three screenshots, screen before the image gets opaque, the screen after the image goes opaque and my canvas components.

Edit: Using UniversalRP - HighQuality(UniversalRenderPipelineAsset)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you considered to do the fade-to-black using a [postprocessing effect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/integration-with-post-processing.html) instead of an overlayed canvas image?

Comment: @Philipp No, I haven't. But, either way, I'd really like to know why this happens. It doesn't make sense to me that a material is overlaying the UI